# adAnalytics return too few metrics

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using this URL:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAnalytics?q=analytics&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2022&timeGranularity=MONTHLY&companies=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{ORG_ID}&pivot=ACCOUNT
```

And the answer I get is like:

```
{'clicks': 54, 'impressions': 19227, 'pivotValues': ['urn:li:sponsoredAccount:{ACCOUNT_ID}'], 'dateRange': {'start': {'month': 4, 'day': 1, 'year': 2022}, 'end': {'month': 4, 'day': 30, 'year': 2022}}}
```

The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting?view=li-lms-2022-11&tabs=http) states that there is a ton of metrics, but I only get those two: 'clicks' and 'impressions'.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the number of metrics that can be obtained is 20 and in order to get the metrics you have to add a query parameter 'fields' in which you put the names of desired metric one after another, separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

may i know where is the fields you put at? is after the pivot or remove the pivot direct replace it to fields?

Comment: Should post as comment